# Formatting ls output without tab using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, ls

My question may seem fairly simple, I'm a beginner at bash scripting still, but I'm trying to format my ls output without using a tab when I print with awk.

Here is my current command that I'm running:

```
ls -al | sed 1d | awk '{print $1" ",$6" ", $7"\t", $9}'
```

and it prints out the following

```
drwx------  Feb  13     .
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  5      ..
-rw-r--r--  Jan  21     .alias
-rw-r--r--  Feb  13     .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  Jan  29     .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  Jan  21     .bash_profile~
-rw-r--r--  Feb  13     .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  Jan  21     .bashrc~
drwxr-xr-x  Jan  3      csc135
drwxr-xr-x  Aug  13     csc136
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  9      csc235
drwxr-xr-x  Oct  19     csc237
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  18     csc310
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  6      csc325
```

I have also attempted using a space:

```
ls -al | sed 1d | awk '{print $1"  ",$6" ", $7" ", $9}'
```

which prints the following (quite bothersome):

```
drwx------   Feb  13  .
drwxr-xr-x   Feb  5  ..
-rw-r--r--   Jan  21  .alias
-rw-r--r--   Feb  13  .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   Jan  29  .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   Jan  21  .bash_profile~
-rw-r--r--   Feb  13  .bashrc
-rw-r--r--   Jan  21  .bashrc~
drwxr-xr-x   Jan  3  csc135
drwxr-xr-x   Aug  13  csc136
drwxr-xr-x   Feb  9  csc235
drwxr-xr-x   Oct  19  csc237
drwxr-xr-x   Feb  18  csc310
drwxr-xr-x   Feb  6  csc325
```

Is there any way to make it nicer looking like this?

```
drwx------  Feb  13  .
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  5   ..
-rw-r--r--  Jan  21  .alias
-rw-r--r--  Feb  13  .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  Jan  29  .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  Jan  21  .bash_profile~
-rw-r--r--  Feb  13  .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  Jan  21  .bashrc~
drwxr-xr-x  Jan  3   csc135
drwxr-xr-x  Aug  13  csc136
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  9   csc235
drwxr-xr-x  Oct  19  csc237
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  18  csc310
drwxr-xr-x  Feb  6   csc325
```

Comment: Are you just trying to pretty format it so that it looks like a table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One automatic option that comes to mind is [`column`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html):

```
$ ls -al | sed 1d | awk '{print $1,$6,$7,$9}' | column -t
drwxr-xr-x+  Feb  3   .
drwxrwxrwt+  Oct  9   ..
-rw-------   Feb  12  .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x   Oct  9   .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x   Feb  3   .bashrc
drwx------+  Feb  2   .cache
-rwxr-xr-x   Oct  9   .inputrc
-rwxr-xr-x   Feb  14  .mkshrc
-rwxr-xr-x   Oct  9   .profile
drwxrwx---+  Dec  13  .ssh
```

Note the `-t` flag used for `column`:

> -t, --table
>                 Determine the number of columns the input contains and create
>                 a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default,
>                 or with the characters supplied using the --output-separator
>                 option.  Table output is useful for pretty-printing.

Another way would be to used fixed lengths:

```
$ ls -al | sed 1d | awk '{printf "%-12s %-3s %-2s %s\n", $1,$6,$7,$9}'
drwxr-xr-x+  Feb 3  .
drwxrwxrwt+  Oct 9  ..
-rw-------   Feb 12 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x   Oct 9  .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x   Feb 3  .bashrc
drwx------+  Feb 2  .cache
-rwxr-xr-x   Oct 9  .inputrc
-rwxr-xr-x   Feb 14 .mkshrc
-rwxr-xr-x   Oct 9  .profile
drwxrwx---+  Dec 13 .ssh
```

There is another example of this in the [GNU Awk User's guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html).

Comment: Thank you! column -t was definitely helpful! I'll probably consider making an alias out of this.

Comment: When you do `ls -al` it shows a trailing slash for directories. i.e. `./`. Is there a way to avoid loosing the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -al|awk  'NR>1{print $1,$6,$7,$9}'|column -t
```

you don't need to use sed to delete the first line. Awk can do this if NR>1 print

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that tidbit of advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all unnecessary pipes by using features of `awk`.

```
ls -al | awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR>1 { print $1, $6, $7, $9 }'
```

- Use `NR>1` to get rid of the unnecessary `sed` to delete the first row.
- Use `OFS` variable to set the output field separator to tab there by removing the need for `column`.

Comment: hey Jaypal, long time no see and congrats on the switch to Intuit